# How can I check if a function can be written as $a * \sin (b * x + c) + d$?

Tags: pattern-matching, algebraic-manipulation, argument-patterns

I want to write a function that takes another function, say $f(x)$ and a variable $x$ as input and return `True` it this function can be written in the form `a*Sin[b*x + c] + d`, `False` otherwise. For example:

```
GetSinForm[1 + x^2,x]
False

GetSinForm[Cos[x]^2,x]
True
```

My idea is to convert the function with the TrigToExp and to check if the form is the typical sine-like form, namely $f(x) =\frac{1}{2i}(e^{-i\pi x} + e^{+i \pi x})$ and to check the matcing with `MatchQ` but this last function is too strict with pattern and I get almost always `False`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a differential equations/operator approach, leading to mathematics-based solutions instead of expression-matching ones.  As the OP observes, matching algebraic expressions with expression patterns can be tricky, despite *Mathematica's* `Optional` patterns and `Default` values.  For trigonometric functions it is usually trickier since, as @alx observes, trig functions have automatic simplification rules that change, for instance, `Sin[t + Pi/2]` to `Cos[t]`. Sometimes a mathematical approach is simpler or more robust.

*Mathematical background*

The expression $y = a * \sin (b * x + c)$ is the general solution to
$$y'' + b^2 y = 0 \,,$$
and thus $y = a * \sin (b * x + c) + d$ is the general solution to
$$y''' + b^2 y' = 0\,.\tag{1}$$
Even further, it is the general solution to 
$${d \over dx} {y''' \over y'} = {d \over dx} \left(-b^2\right) \,,$$
or equivalently
$$y'y^{(4)}-y''y''' = 0 \,.\tag{2}$$
Equation (2) is equivalent to the vanishing of the second-order Wronskian of $y'$ and $y'''$,
$$W \equiv \left|\matrix{ y' & y''' \\ y'' & y^{(4)} \\}\right| = 0 \,. \tag{3}$$
The condition $W=0$ is equivalent to $y'$ and $y'''$ being linearly dependent.  A fourth-order ODE is as far as we can go, since the form $y = a * \sin (b * x + c) + d$ has four parameters.

*Solution methods*

A solution based on (1), using the internal, undocumented function `` Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod `` is the following:

```
ClearAll[sinQ];
sinQ[f_, x_] := 
  With[{b = 2 Pi/Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[f, x]},
   Simplify[D[f, {x, 3}] + b^2 D[f, x]] === 0 /; FreeQ[b, $Failed]];
sinQ[__] = False;
```

A solution based on (2) is the following:

```
ClearAll[sinQ];
sinQ[f_, x_] := 
  Simplify[D[f, {x, 1}] D[f, {x, 4}] - D[f, {x, 2}] D[f, {x, 3}]] === 0;
```

And a solution based on (3), using the alternative `PossibleZeroQ` to simplifying the Wronskian, is the following:

```
ClearAll[sinQ];
sinQ[f_, x_] := 
  PossibleZeroQ[Det@Partition[Rest@NestList[D[#, x] &, f, 4], 2]];
```

*Examples*

```
sinQ[a*Sin[b*x + c] + d, x]
(*  True  *)

sinQ[5 Sin[4 (t - 1)] + Cos[2 t]^2 - 1, t]
(*  True  *)

sinQ[5 Sin[4 (t - 1)] + Cos[4 t]^2, t]
(*  False  *)
```

Note: Only the method that uses `PossibleZeroQ` works on the following example, which has approximate real parameter values:

```
sinQ[5 Sin[4. (t - 1)] + Cos[2. t + 0.1]^2, t]
(*  True  *)
```

One can use `PossibleZeroQ` in the other methods. It will work with the second example but not with the first, because `` Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod `` fails to recognize the function with approximate coefficients as periodic.  One could `Rationalize` the argument `f` in that case, if one wanted to extend that method to such as examples as this last one.

**Addendum**

It wasn't asked for but here is a way to compute the parameters.  One can compute the offset `d` and amplitude `b` from integrals, which for a sine curve can be computed exactly and quickly with the trapezoid rule with a sampling of four points per period (see `trapsample` below).  This can be used to verify `sinQ`, about whose accuracy a question arose.

```
ClearAll[sinParameters];
sinParameters[e_, t_] := Module[
   {df, aa, bb, cc, dd, trapsample},
   df = NestList[D[#, t] &, e, 4]; (* y''' + b^2 y' == 0 *)
   ( bb = Simplify@ Sqrt[-df[[4]]/df[[2]]];
     trapsample = Map[e /. t -> # &, Pi {1/4, 3/4, 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2}/bb];
     dd = Simplify@ Mean@ trapsample[[3 ;;]];
     aa = Simplify@ Sqrt[2 Mean[(trapsample[[;; 4]] - dd)^2]];
     cc = Simplify@ ArcSin[(e - dd)/aa /. t -> 0];
     If[df[[2]] != aa bb /. t -> -cc/bb, (* adjust quadrant of ArcSin *)
      aa = -aa;     (* alternatively, leave aa as is and set cc=Pi-cc *)
      cc = -cc
      ];
     Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> {aa, bb, cc, dd}]
     ) /; PossibleZeroQ[Det@Partition[Rest@df, 2]] (* same test as sinQ *)
   ];
```

On the second example above, @alx noted that @alx's method returns `False`.  One can see that it can be written in the desired form from the following:

```
fn = 5 Sin[4 (t - 1)] + Cos[2 t]^2 - 1;
a * Sin[b*t + c] + d /. sinParameters[fn, t]
(*
  -(1/2)  -  1/2 Sqrt[101 - 20 Sin[4]] *
      Sin[ 4 t  -  ArcSin[(1 - 10 Sin[4])/Sqrt[101 - 20 Sin[4]]] ]
*)

fn - % // TrigToExp // FullSimplify
(*  0  *)
```

I wrote a symbolic analysis solver for the parameters, but the code is about twice as long and runs more than a 100 times more slowly.  I didn't think it worth sharing.

```
sinQ[fn, t] // RepeatedTiming
sinParameters[fn, t] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.000087, True}
  {0.00054, {
    a -> -(1/2) Sqrt[101 - 20 Sin[4]],
    b -> 4, 
    c -> -ArcSin[(1 - 10 Sin[4])/Sqrt[101 - 20 Sin[4]]],
    d -> -(1/2)}}
*)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something wrong?

Comment: (Not the downvoter). A slightly related observation. I was a little surprised to see this call to `PossibleZeroQ` return `False`:  `{a, b, c, d} = CloudGet["https://wolfr.am/HclVT0Om"];
func = 5 Sin[4 (t - 1)] + Cos[2 t]^2 - 1;
PossibleZeroQ[a Sin[b t + c] + d - func]`

Comment: @ChipHurst Yes, it happens for `(-(1/2) - 1/2 Sqrt[101 - 20 Sin[4]] Sin[4 t - ArcTan[1/5 Sec[4] (-(1/2) + 5 Sin[4])]]) - func`, too; but `PossibleZeroQ` is wrong, isn't it? (I'm not sure if you have a point beyond that there are limitations on symbolic computation; however, `sinQ` does correctly identify `func` as being able to be written in the OP's sine form.)

Comment: Yes, `PossibleZeroQ` is wrong in this case. When plugging in explicit values for `t`, `PossibleZeroQ` returns `True` and throws a message.

Comment: @MichaelE2, +1. But I probably misunderstood OP requirements: I thought his function `f(x)` should be represented with only one `Sin` term, but your 2nd example can be written with 2 `Sin` terms, this gives False in my approach.

Comment: @Alx Thanks for the upvote. The second example can also be written in the form `a Sin[b x + c] + d` with one sine, either in Chip Hurst's way or in the simpler way in my last comment.  However both `FullSimplify` and `PossibleZeroQ` fail to show this.  I verified it numerically, as well as by hand, using the identity `Cos[2 t]^2 == (1 + Cos[4 t])/2`, the angle addition identities, and the identity for writing a linear combination of `Sin[4 t]` and `Cos[4 t]` as a single sine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TrigReduce` to come to form with multiple angles instead of powers and then use `MatchQ` to compare the result with `Sin[...]` pattern. I also use here `Inactive[Sin]` to keep results of conversion `Cos` terms to corresponding `Sin` terms:

```
MatchQ[(TrigReduce[expr]//Expand)/.{Sin[x_] -> Inactive[Sin][x],
Cos[x_] -> Inactive[Sin][x + \[Pi]/2]},
a_. Inactive[Sin][b_. x + c_.] + d_. /; FreeQ[d, x]
```

So this will match only to `a Sin[b x+c]+d`, where all `a, b, c, d` are constants.

Comment: Thanks, it works but there is a small bug, for example with `Cos[x]^2 + x`. In this case, even if the function cannot be expressed as Sin/Cos, the snippet returns `True` .

Comment: @MarcusGarvey, I edited `FreeQ[]` term, now it works with your example in comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only intend to check the identity a simple workaround might be

```
NMinimize[NIntegrate[(a Sin[b x + c] + d - Cos[x]^2)^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {a, b,c, d}]
(*{9.22063*10^-15, {a -> -0.5, b -> -2., c -> -1.5708, d -> 0.5}}*)
```